# Meteor mongo array each returns error

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I have a collection with following entry

```
{ 
    "_id" : "6z2pQDYozQxEyPZYv", 
    "userId" : "b2dQ6SuPrwmPsLsg8", 
    "communicatingWith" : [ "KMT74bWPoZxDSKdrx", "KMT74bWPoZxDSKdrx" ] 
}
```

when I query mongo through meteor for the field communicatingWith , if I do a `console.log(communicatingWith)`, the output is 
`[ 'KMT74bWPoZxDSKdrx', 'KMT74bWPoZxDSKdrx' ]`.

Even when I do `console.log(communicatingWith.length)` the output is 2

But when I do

```
communicatingWith.each(function(item){console.log(item)})
```

it throws error saying

```
Exception while invoking method 'createPrivateMsgHanger' TypeError: Object KMT74bWPoZxDSKdrx,KMT74bWPoZxDSKdrx has no method 'each'
```

Can you please help me understand where things are wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`.each` is a jQuery function
pure javascript uses `Array.forEach(function(item) { //do something here})`

Answer (score 0):

I could get around this problem using the following statement
let arr = Array.from(loggedInUserHanger.communicatingWith);
once I have the arr, I can use all Array functions

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be using `forEach`. I don't remember seing `each` in JS before https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach